# Xcode 5 Storyboard created UIViewController layout not being called when creating new VC programmatically

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, storyboard, xcode5

I've been trying to use the new xcode 5 storyboard paradigm and not create .xib files specifically. I've got two VCs - the first was created by Xcode, the second was created by dropping a UIViewController into InterfaceBuilder.

My issue is that even though I've given my second VC a custom class and imported the headers into the first VC, when I create the second VC programatically it doesn't conform to the design I set in InterfaceBuilder. The first one does.

My code to create the second VC goes something like this (it's inside an ImagePickerControllerDelegate method) :

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    NCPhotoViewController *newController = [[NCPhotoViewController alloc] init];
    newController.theImage = chosenImage;
    ** NEW CODE newController.theImageView.image = newController.theImage;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }];
```

...which seems fine, and does what I want it to - brings up a new view controller. Thing is, it doesn't load with the layout I set in IB. I tried exchanging the the `alloc] init]` method to `initWithNibName:bundle:` but realised that I didn't a nib... is there a way I can make this connection in IB without creating a .xib file, or have I misunderstood the new flow of Xcode 5? I'm aware that there's a Storyboard ID attribute in the Identity Inspector, but how do I use that to my advantage? I don't want to do things "the old way" if they're not being put there by default...

TL;DR - I'd like my IB laid-out ViewController to look the way it's intended when called programatically in Xcode 5 default storyboard flow.

Added some code to make the imageview of the new viewcontroller have an image, but it doesn't appear...

EDIT: I had to add `self.theImageView.image = theImage;` in the `viewDidLoad` method in my new viewcontroller.h file - but shouldn't it already do that with the code I've written?

Comment: you need to create viewController with frame.

Comment: Even after you created view controller its view and thus view hierarchy may not be created until you explicitly access the view (e.g. until controller is about to display). So all initialization of UI elements should be performed in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear: methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you setup your controller in storyboard you should load it from it. If your code is already in some controller from the same storyboard you can do it the following way:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = self.storyboard;
NCPhotoViewController * newController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];
...
```

You also need to set Storyboard ID for your view controller to "SomeIdentifier" so storyboard will know which controller to instantiate. Here's how it will look in Utilities pane in IB:
 [image]

Comment: This worked excellently, thanks for a great answer. I do now have a problem where the UIImageView that I try and set programatically isn't appearing in the newly loaded ViewController, but I might just keep cracking away at that.

Comment: I added some more code to highlight my further issue - how to make the image appear in the imageview of the new viewcontroller - all I'm getting is a blank new view controller